# Matplotlib hexbin: How to avoid displaying bins where np.mean is zero

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is not the same as setting `mincnt=1`. Is it possible to remove the colored bin when the mean value of the cell is zero? See the example of the code below. I would like points like `1` not to be drawing. Setting `mincnt=1` would remove points in the cell that appear once and have mean>=0

```
d1 = {'Size': {0: 0, 1: 0,2: 0, 3: 5, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 8, 7: 5, 8: 9, 9: 3, 10: 6, 11: 7, 12: 5, 13: 6, 14: 5, 15: 5, 16: 7, 17: 6, 18: 0},
         'X': {0: -0.86602540400000005, 1: 0.86602540400000005, 2: 0.0, 3: -0.34641016200000002, 4: -0.28867513500000003, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.10825317499999999, 7: 0.34641016200000002, 8: 0.0, 9: -0.86602540400000005, 10: -0.43301270200000003, 11: 0.0, 12: -0.17320508100000001, 13: 0.43301270200000003, 14: 0.34641016200000002, 15: 0.34641016200000002, 16: 0.0, 17: 0.0, 18: 0.0},
         'Y': {0: -0.5, 1: -0.5, 2: 1.0, 3: 0.40000000000000002, 4: -0.5, 5: 1.0, 6: 0.0625, 7: 0.40000000000000002, 8: 0.0, 9: -0.5, 10: 0.25, 11: 0.14285714300000002, 12: -0.5, 13: 0.25, 14: 0.40000000000000002, 15: 0.40000000000000002, 16: 0.14285714300000002, 17: -0.5, 18: 0.0}}

test1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
import numpy as np
plot_format = {
    "gridsize":15,
    "cmap":plt.cm.YlOrRd,
    #"mincnt":1,
    "vmin":1,
    "vmax":9,        
    "reduce_C_function":np.mean
}

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.hexbin(test1["X"], test1["Y"], C=test1.Size, **plot_format)
ax.axis([-1, 1, -0.8, 1.2])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the counts for each bin using the `.get_array()` method of the `matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection` object returned by `hexbin`, then use this to set the alpha channel for the face colors of the patches:

```
hb = ax.hexbin(test1["X"], test1["Y"], C=test1.Size, **plot_format)

# you might need to force a draw event here, otherwise `hb.get_colors()` can return
# incorrect values
ax.figure.canvas.draw()

counts = hb.get_array()         # get the counts (n,)
colors = hb.get_facecolors()    # get the facecolors of the patches (n, 4)
colors[:, 3] = counts > 0       # set the alpha channel to 0 where counts <= 0
hb.set_facecolors(colors)       # update the facecolors of the patches
```

Comment: smart! However when I try it it seems that `colors` has shape `(1,4)` instead of `(n,4)`. Where is the catch?

Comment: You might need to force a draw event between plotting the hexbins and calling `get_colors`, e.g. by calling `ax.figure.canvas.draw()` or `plt.draw()`

Comment: Niiice! Worked like a breeze! Thank you!

Comment: It's still not ideal since setting the facecolors manually means that the array values are no longer automatically mapped to colors via the colormap (if you try changing the colormap after applying my hack you'll see what I mean). It seems like an unnecessary limitation of the API IMO.